# Как в регулярном выражении исключить слово?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Я знаю про x(?!y) - находит x, только если за x не следует y. Но мне нужно исключать слово вне зависимости от того где оно стоит.

Найти букву А но исключить такие слова: арбуз, абандон и т.д.

Comment: Задачу обязательно решить одним регулярным выражением? Нет возможности удалить слова-исключения из строки и затем применить регулярное выражение?

Comment: добавь примеры входных строк и что хочешь видеть на выходе

Comment: @cheops вообще это регулярка для работы с текстом в notepad++, в коде я бы и сам всё реализовал, поэтому нужно одно регулярное выражение.

Comment: @Khipster, если это для `notepad++` почему стоит метка _javascript_?

Comment: @Grundy а в notepad++ такие же регулярные выражения как и в JavaScript, ну или я могу написать скриптик конечно если никак одной регуляркой.

Comment: @Khipster, почему ты так думаешь?

Comment: @Khipster 1. Не такие же - в NPP более расширенный синтаксис. 2. Следует в вопросе написать, что именно ты хочешь сделать. Потому что так - непонятно.

Comment: В Notepad++  используется библиотека Boost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Относительно

> Найти букву `А` но исключить такие слова: `арбуз`, `абандон` и т.д.

В Notepad++ используйте захватывающую подмаску с чередованиями и условный шаблон замены:

```
(\b(?:арбуз|абандон)\w*)|а
```

Заменить на

```
(?1$1:я)
```

Т.е. с помощью `(\b(?:арбуз|абандон)\w*)|а` мы найдем и сохраним все слова исключения (с окончаниями или без с помощью `\w*`) в группе №1, и при совпадении эти слова будут восстановлены в тексте с помощью `?1$1` (если первая подмаска найдена, восстанавливаем), а буква `а` будет изменена/удалена во всех остальных случаях (`:я`).

Относительно использования параметра *Match case* решайте сами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вместо `\w` можно использовать `\p{L}` для нахождения только букв Юникода.

Answer (score 1):

Проверить, что строка не содержит заданных слов:

```
/^((?!арбуз|абандон).)*$/i
```

Выбрать все буквы `а`, которые не входят в заданные слова:

```
s.match(/арбуз|абандон|а|$/gi).filter(m => m.length===1)
```

Comment: у тебя в `match` подставлено другая регулярка

Comment: @Grundy, я знаю. Это разные регулярки. Чем не устраивают?

Comment: Я, честно говоря не совсем понимаю, что ты делаешь :)

Comment: @Grundy, дополнил ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а почему во втором регулярном выражении конец строки $? В первом понятно зачем, во втором - нет. Можете описать и вообще остановиться на второй строке более подробно?

Comment: @cheops, по `$` он гарантированно найдёт пустую строку. Без него на строке без букв `а` получился бы null, из-за чего упал бы `.filter`. А так мы точно что-то найдём.